# How do I relate the string I get from the combobox to a specific float I want in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

Here's the situation:

I need to get a value (float) that is different from the selected option in the combobox (a string) and I don't know how to do it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

combo = ttk.Combobox(top, state="readonly")
combo["values"] = ("DAP", "MAP", "SPS", "SPT")
combo.current(0)
combo.grid(row=row, column=1)
```

DAP=46

MAP=52

SPS=21

SPT=46

`combo.get()` will fetch me "DAP" (if DAP is selected in the combobox obviously) and I want to get 46 in this case.

So when an option is chosen from the combobox I need to get a float (e.g. when someone selects DAP in the combobox I need to get or get returned 46 as a float). With `combo.get()` I'll get 'DAP' (If DAP is selected for example) and I want to get 46 instead (as a float).I need to relate each gotten string with the corresponding float.

I use it on this formula:

```
dosis = 50 / float(combo_dict.get((combo.get())) / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dict` ([[Python]: Mapping Types — dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)):

```
combo_dict = {
    "DAP": 46,
    "MAP": 52,
    "SPS": 21,
    "SPT": 46,
}
```

and its usage (as current values are `int`s, convert them to `float`s):

```
float(combo_dict[combo.get()])
```

or better (in case the string returned by the *combo* is not present in `combo_dict`: [[Python]: **get**(*key[, default]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)):

```
float(combo_dict.get(combo.get(), -1))
```

Comment: Excellent, will try that!

Comment: It worked but without the -1 in combo_dict.get(combo.get(), -1)

Comment: What do you mean? It's better to leave the -1 there because if you do `float(combo_dict.get("dummy"))`  you'll get a `TypeError`, while if you leave it there, you'll get *-1.0*.

Comment: It says: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: It is impossible to get other values than the ones listed there, I'll never get "dummie" for example

Comment: The "never say never" rule also applies here. If you update the combobox (add a new item) and forget to update `combo_dict`, you would run into that situation, and get a`TypeError` (like you got earlier). I'd say to leave it there... it doesn't hurt anyone :), but if you want to return `None` so be it. It's your choice after all.

Comment: I mean I really apreciate your -1 and I unterstand that is for future purposes but when I add it I get that error

Comment: No, its purpose it's to prevent the `TypeError`. If you get that `TypeError` when -1 is **in** the code, then the error is somewhere else, in the code that calls `combo_dict.get(`. Also I don't know where the `int` (in the error) comes from because `float(combo_dict.get(combo.get(), -1))` returns a `float` (-1.0) when the string is not  in `combo_dict`. Probably if you would edit the question and add the code that uses `combo_dict`, I could figure it out. Question: does it happen if you replace -1 by 0?

Comment: I've edited the question, It happens whenever I add something on the X = float(combo_dict.get(combo.get(), X))

Comment: You messed up the parentheses: `combo_dict.get((combo.get()))`: `(combo.get())` works fine (evaluates to `combo.get()`), but if you add anything else: `combo_dict.get((combo.get(), -1))`, `(combo.get(), -1)` evaluates to a *tuple* which is not found in the dictionary, and `get` returns `None`. Lose one set of parentheses: `dosis = 50 / float(combo_dict.get(combo.get(), -1) / 100)`, and it will behave like I said.

Comment: I knew it was something with the parenthesis, thank you very much!